# Keep python program runing even if it cannot connect to mysql databse

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have program continuously measuring some data and storing them to the mysql database. The problem I'm facing is, when the server cannot connect to the database my Python program stops working for some reason (e.g DB maintenance).

What I need here is to just keep my program running even if cannot connect to the database.

```
  def MyDB():
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="X.X.X.X", user="user1", passwd="passwd1", db="DB1")
    cursor = db.cursor()    
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Table1 (timestamp, x1, x2, x3, x4) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (x1, x2, x3, x4))
    db.commit()
    db.close()
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print (e)
#MyDB

while 1:
   # Here my code doing some measurement
   Measurement()      
   # Here I called MyDB to store my measured data
   MyDB()
```

The error message I get is : 
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X')

And my program stop.

Comment: Hi, you should provide more information, like, source code, exception/s that the software is throwing when failing, how are you running your python app, is it as a service? from the terminal? Cheers

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. The program running from an ubunter server from terminal.

Comment: It's not your entire code. How do you call `MyDB()`?

Comment: MyDB() is called inside a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your program to continue running no matter what failure happens in the function MyDb, My suggestion would be to wrap the function calling with try...except.

```
while True:
    Measurement()      
    try:
        MyDB()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

You might want to use the **[traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html)** module to print a better stacktrace of the caught exception.

Comment: Tried your suggestion still the same thing the program stop.